# Module not found typescript

Tags: class, validation, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I want import this module [class validator](https://github.com/pleerock/class-validator) and when I complie my App with webpack and babel, I don't know why the console show this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-validator' in '/****/***/projects/***/****/src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 30:24-50
```

I import this module:

```
import {Validator} from 'class-validator';

// Validation methods
const validator = new Validator();

class GlobalEntity{}
export default Global Entity;
```

and my tsconfig.json is :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "CommonJS"

  },
  "exclude": ["./node_modules","dist"],
  "files": ["./typings/index.d.ts", "./src/index.ts"]
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Alex

Comment: Is the class-validator.ts in the same directory like index.ts?

Comment: yes, is a module from another person and he have the index.ts in the root